# UI very distorted using jquery Trigger.io apps

Tags: trigger.io

**I have couple of questions**:

1) I am creating apps using [Trigger.io](http://trigger.io) and trying to make a search form that loads listview and shows data. However the UI is very distorted when i tried on android simulator and i also tested on my android tablet.

All the rounded borders and icons in list view looks very messed up. Does anyone have any solution to this?

2) How can i add ads in my apps? Can i use admob?

3) How can i scale YouTube video according to screen size?

Answer (score 0):

1) Is your HTML displaying properly in browsers? Unfortunately, we don't control the HTML rendering, so you'll need to write your markup in a webkit-compatible way.

2) We have an AdMob integration in our medium-term plans

3) If you want full-screen video playback, see [forge.media](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/media.html). For inline video, we should behave in the same way as the stock browser - if not, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

1) Android 2.x has f'ugly rendering of CSS rounded corners, combined with older 2.x handsets having lower res displays leads to some really freaky looking borders, shadows and bevels. Also slows down the page a lot - I would avoid these css effects if possible if you want to target these devices.